# CSS: Truncate button-text and keep icon in a flex-box

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to make a button display some text that is truncated and a icon. I want the icon to be present even when the text starts to truncate.

So the problem is that when the text is truncated - the icon is also removed.
I could solve this by having the icon as a separate button - but that would make the keyboard navigation weird.

See my example below:

```css
.bar {
  display: flex;
}

.item2 {
  border: none;
  background-color: white;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<nav class="bar">
  <span class="item1">
    TEST
  </span>
  <button type="button" class="item2">
    <span class="item2_text">This is a veeeery long text that we want to overflow so that
    everything is on one line and does not break our content line in two or overflow</span>
    <span class="item2_icon">
      <svg version="1.1" id="Capa_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="18px" height="10px" viewBox="0 0 451.847 451.847" style="enable-background:new 0 0 451.847 451.847;" xml:space="preserve">
        <g>
          <path d="M225.923,354.706c-8.098,0-16.195-3.092-22.369-9.263L9.27,151.157c-12.359-12.359-12.359-32.397,0-44.751
 c12.354-12.354,32.388-12.354,44.748,0l171.905,171.915l171.906-171.909c12.359-12.354,32.391-12.354,44.744,0
 c12.365,12.354,12.365,32.392,0,44.751L248.292,345.449C242.115,351.621,234.018,354.706,225.923,354.706z" />
        </g>
      </svg>
    </span>
  </button>
  <span class="menu">
    Stuff
  </span>
</nav>
```

I have tried to move the text-overflow: ellipsis to the item2_text but it does not work.
Can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to have a dynamic approach don't give the text a fixed width, play with the calc property.
First, move the ellipsis code to the span instead of having it on the button itself and add `inline-block` property in order to have the ellipsis one to work.
Then set the item with to be 100% and subtract the width  of the icon (along with some extra pixels).

```css
.bar {
  display: flex;
}

.item2 {
  border: none;
  background-color: white;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.item2_text {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
  width: calc(100% - 25px);
}
```

```html
<nav class="bar">
  <span class="item1">
    TEST
  </span>
  <button type="button" class="item2">
    <span class="item2_text">This is a veeeery long text that we want to overflow so that
    everything is on one line and does not break our content line in two or overflow</span>
    <span class="item2_icon">
      <svg version="1.1" id="Capa_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="18px" height="10px" viewBox="0 0 451.847 451.847" style="enable-background:new 0 0 451.847 451.847;" xml:space="preserve">
        <g>
          <path d="M225.923,354.706c-8.098,0-16.195-3.092-22.369-9.263L9.27,151.157c-12.359-12.359-12.359-32.397,0-44.751
 c12.354-12.354,32.388-12.354,44.748,0l171.905,171.915l171.906-171.909c12.359-12.354,32.391-12.354,44.744,0
 c12.365,12.354,12.365,32.392,0,44.751L248.292,345.449C242.115,351.621,234.018,354.706,225.923,354.706z" />
        </g>
      </svg>
    </span>
  </button>
  <span class="menu">
    Stuff
  </span>
</nav>
```

Comment: True, it's a preventing form of rushing to pick an answer too soon